# Cannot import Android project

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, android-studio

I am in trouble. I did create my Android applications on Windows. But 2 weeks ago I changed my OS to Ubuntu and installed Android Studio. So problem is that now on Ubuntu I cannot open my project correctly it gives error

Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:

The project 'Radiasiya Radio' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try deleting .gradle folder from the home(ubuntu). It is usually hidden. Then open Android Studio with your project and go to Tools>Android>Sync Project with Gradle. It will download gradle again.

Comment: I tried but anyway it did not work.